# Uniform random distribution on a unit disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, geometric-probability

> a) A point is uniformly chosen in the unit disk $0 ≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$. Find the probability that its
>   distance from the origin is less than $r$, for $0 ≤ r ≤ 1$.
>
> b) Compute its expected distance from the origin.
>
> c)Let the coordinates of the point be $(X, Y )$. Determine the marginal p.d.f. of $X$. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I did the part a) using geometry that the area of the circle with a radius of $r$ is divided by the area of the unit circle, such that $$P(R\leq r)=\frac{\pi r^2}{\pi\cdot 1^2}=r^2$$

Part b) is attempted to solve by differentiating the cdf, such that $$f(r)=\frac{d}{dr}r^2=2r,\hspace{3mm} E(R)=\int_{0}^1r\times 2r\,dr=\frac{2}{3}.$$

But this result does not seem to be right... And I do not know about part c)

A simulation was done using python to visualize this distribution,
and it gives image like this. [image: Distribution plot]

Why are the points concentrated near the central area?

````
from scipy.stats import uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math  
r = uniform.rvs(scale =1,size=5000)
pi = 3.14159265359
theta = uniform.rvs(scale =2*pi,size=5000)
x = []
y = []
for i in range (5000):
    x.append(r[i]*math.cos(theta[i]) )
    y.append(r[i]*math.sin(theta[i]) )
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,2,3])
ax.scatter(x, y)```
````

Comment: The probability a point is closer to the origin than $r$ is the area of a disk of radius $r$ to that of the disk of radius $1$.

Comment: Why do you think your result for part b) isn't right?

Comment: For independence in (c): Is it possible for $X>\frac34$? Is it possible for $Y>\frac34$? Are both possible simultaneously?

Comment: @joriki Hi! Thanks for your reply. I tried to simulate the scattered point distribution on python and found that the points concentrate more near the center. I thought if the answer is 2/3 there would be a thick ring of points near $r=\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: @Luka: Judging from your code, you didn't simulate the given uniform distribution over the circle; you simulated a uniform distribution for $r$. This will indeed concentrate near the centre, since it's too high near the centre compared to the radial distribution of the uniform distribution over the circle, which is (as you wrote yourself) $2r$, i.e. not uniform; in particular, it's $0$ at the centre, whereas your uniform radial distribution has the same value at the centre as at the perimeter and thus concentrates the points at the centre.

Comment: @Luka: Moreover, if you did use the correct radial distribution for the uniform distribution over the circle (or any other method of generating points uniformly in the circle, e.g. generating them uniformly in a square and using only the ones that lie in the circle), then you shouldn't expect a concentration anywhere, including the expected radius $\frac23$, since the distribution is uniform and thus by definition not concentrated anywhere.

Comment: Here's [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly) on writing code to generate points uniformly in a disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results for parts a) and b) are correct.

For part c), note that $Y\le\sqrt{1-X^2}$. Thus, knowing $X$ reduces the possible range of $Y$, so the two variables can’t be independent.

To find the marginal distribution of $X$ you can use $P(x\le X\le X+\mathrm dx)=\frac1\pi\left(2\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\mathrm dx$, since the density in the circle is uniformly $\frac1\pi$ and an infinitesimal strip of width $\mathrm dx$ at $x$ has area $\left(2\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\mathrm dx$. Thus $f_X(x)=\frac2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}$. (Incidentally, this tells you that $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac\pi2$.)

Answer (score -6):

1. The probability a point is closer to the origin than $r$ is the area of a disk of radius $r$ to that of the disk of radius $1$.  That is, $\frac{\pi r^2}{ \pi 1^2} = r^2$.
2. The expected distance is $\int\limits_{s=0}^r s (2 \pi s)\ ds$
   as can be easily seen:

[image]

3. $p(y\mid x) = {\cal U}[-\sqrt{1-x^2}, +\sqrt{1-x^2}]$

as can be easily seen here:

[image]

And clearly $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.  If $X=.99$, then $Y$ must be small...

Comment: But $\frac{\pi r^2}{\pi 1^2}=r^2$? And how can the expected distance contain a free variable $r$? The OP had already correctly solved parts a) and b).

Comment: Because $r$ *IS* a free variable.  You've given some arbitrary cutoff, $r$, and asked what is the expected distance from the origin to it.  If you tell me that $r=0$, then I know that the distance is $0$.  If you tell me it is $r=.378$ well then...  If you set $r=1$, well then...

Comment: As joriki pointed out, your answer to 2) doesn't make sense. The question is: "What is the average distance to the origin of a point chosen uniformly from the unit disc?" The answer should be a number, not an expression in $r$. (Note that there is no quantity $r$ in the question). I also don't understand the appearance of $2\pi$ in your answer. The OP already correctly calculated the pdf as the derivative of the cdf.

Comment: Moreover, part c) asks for the marginal distribution, not the conditional distribution.

Comment: @André3000:  I read this:  Find the probability that its distance from the origin is less than , for 0≤≤1.  Compute its expected distance from the origin.